# Understanding code from tensorflow c++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am new to c++ and I am trying to understand how this code from works , I am able to understand how includeguard works. And also how to use nested namespace gtl and tensorflow.

I want to understand how this code works

```
// This file provides utility functions for use with STL map-like data
// structures, such as std::map and hash_map. Some functions will also work with
// sets, such as ContainsKey().

#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LIB_GTL_MAP_UTIL_H_   
#define TENSORFLOW_LIB_GTL_MAP_UTIL_H_
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace tensorflow {
namespace gtl {

// Returns a pointer to the const value associated with the given key if it
// exists, or NULL otherwise.
template <class Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type* FindOrNull(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key) {
  typename Collection::const_iterator it = collection.find(key);
  if (it == collection.end()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return &it->second;
}

// Same as above but returns a pointer to the non-const value.
template <class Collection>
typename Collection::value_type::second_type* FindOrNull(
    Collection& collection,  // NOLINT
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key) {
  typename Collection::iterator it = collection.find(key);
  if (it == collection.end()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return &it->second;
}

// Returns the pointer value associated with the given key. If none is found,
// NULL is returned. The function is designed to be used with a map of keys to
// pointers.
//
// This function does not distinguish between a missing key and a key mapped
// to a NULL value.
template <class Collection>
typename Collection::value_type::second_type FindPtrOrNull(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key) {
  typename Collection::const_iterator it = collection.find(key);
  if (it == collection.end()) {
    return typename Collection::value_type::second_type();
  }
  return it->second;
}

// Returns a const reference to the value associated with the given key if it
// exists, otherwise returns a const reference to the provided default value.
//
// WARNING: If a temporary object is passed as the default "value,"
// this function will return a reference to that temporary object,
// which will be destroyed at the end of the statement. A common
// example: if you have a map with string values, and you pass a char*
// as the default "value," either use the returned value immediately
// or store it in a string (not string&).
template <class Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& FindWithDefault(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
    const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& value) {
  typename Collection::const_iterator it = collection.find(key);
  if (it == collection.end()) {
    return value;
  }
  return it->second;
}

// Inserts the given key and value into the given collection if and only if the
// given key did NOT already exist in the collection. If the key previously
// existed in the collection, the value is not changed. Returns true if the
// key-value pair was inserted; returns false if the key was already present.
template <class Collection>
bool InsertIfNotPresent(Collection* const collection,
                        const typename Collection::value_type& vt) {
  return collection->insert(vt).second;
}

// Same as above except the key and value are passed separately.
template <class Collection>
bool InsertIfNotPresent(
    Collection* const collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
    const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& value) {
  return InsertIfNotPresent(collection,
                            typename Collection::value_type(key, value));
}

// Looks up a given key and value pair in a collection and inserts the key-value
// pair if it's not already present. Returns a reference to the value associated
// with the key.
template <class Collection>
typename Collection::value_type::second_type& LookupOrInsert(
    Collection* const collection, const typename Collection::value_type& vt) {
  return collection->insert(vt).first->second;
}

// Same as above except the key-value are passed separately.
template <class Collection>
typename Collection::value_type::second_type& LookupOrInsert(
    Collection* const collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
    const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& value) {
  return LookupOrInsert(collection,
                        typename Collection::value_type(key, value));
}

}  // namespace gtl
}  // namespace tensorflow

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LIB_GTL_MAP_UTIL_H_


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{



}
```

I really want to understand how this part works.

```
// exists, or NULL otherwise.
template <class Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type* FindOrNull(
    const Collection& collection,
    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key) {
  typename Collection::const_iterator it = collection.find(key);
  if (it == collection.end()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return &it->second;
}
```

I have used c++ map but I still cannot understand this.
I have never seen how keyword template is used here. 
I have trying very hard to see how this works but maybe my basics are not clear so I cannot comprehend this. Can you please give an example of this is used and a short explanation?

Comment: "I have never seen how keyword template is used here." Have you seen any other uses of keyword `template`? What you have here is ordinary, basic, everyday use of the keyword `template`. Get your favorite book on C++ and read about templates.

Comment: I am sorry but I started learning c++ very recently so maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break that down (I've replaced some complicated types with `int`, `std::string` and `const_iterator` (which may not be an actual type)):

```
template <class Collection>
const int FindOrNull(
    const Collection& collection,
    const std::string& key) {
  const_iterator it = collection.find(key);

  if (it == collection.end())
    return 0;

  return &it->second;
}
```

So here you go - a simple function that takes two parameters and returns an integer. That `template <class Collection>` means that `FindOrNull` is a *template* function, it can take a parameter of (any) type `Collection` unless it doesn't have some required methods/properties (e.g. `Collection::find`).

---

A simple example of a templatized function:

```
template <typename T, typename Y>
auto add(const T &a, const Y &b) -> decltype(a + b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

This function *adds* two... something: two integers, `double`s, `float`s, `std::string`s, whatever *that can be added together*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I try to make sense of things first. Is it okay if I ask a few follow up questions in the comments ?

Comment: @ArafatK, it's okay if they are _very_ closely related to this question and can be thought of as _subsets_ of this one. Although, it's not encouraged to ask 'fully featured' questions in the comments.

Comment: I am able to understand the code and how the scope resolution operator is used here for map . I just have a question. Can you explain the usage of keywords const and typename here ?

Comment: @ArafatK, `const` applied to arguments means they will not be modified by the function, `const` applied to return type means that this function returns a constant. `typename <something> test` tells that `<something>` is a type of a variable called `test`. This type can be rather complicated and the compiler might think that it is a variable or function (like in `Collection::value_type::second_type`), so one may need to help it to compile the code correctly.